# Auto Refresh the List in Sencha Touch Application

Tags: multithreading, sencha-touch, refresh

I am developing an simple Chat Application, I can view the updated data when I click on the REFRESH Button, BUT can I refresh the data at a regular interval from the Server (as my Chat is getting Stored in the Database remotely)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [DelayedTask](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.util.DelayedTask) class of Sencha Touch:

```
//create the delayed task instance with our callback
var task = Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', function() {
    //load the list's store here. The list will be automatically updated
    listComp.getStore().load();    // Assuming your list component is "listComp"
    listComp.refresh();    

    // The task will be called after each 10000 ms
    task.delay(10000);
}, this);

//The function will start after 0 milliseconds
//so we want to start instantly at first
task.delay(0);

//to stop the task, just call the cancel method
//task.cancel();
```

This should work for your case.

Comment: Thanks. tried it and with some tweak in the suggested snippet got my work properly executed. Thanks....

Comment: I've made task as example above. Task is initialized in main controller, but after switching to another view, running task is canceled. Do I need to add other specific configuration?

Comment: Peter O. the task will only cancel if u put in task.cancel();
try to look at the example here. (http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?194202-Autorefresh-List-with-DelayedTask) it is work fine to me. I think u will also.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call your refresh() function at a regular right ?

So you just need to add a `setTimeout("refresh()", 1000);` at the end of your `refresh()` function. Then you just need to call it when your app startup.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello, let me add this to my code and would revert back to you if I need any further help. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll be interested in socket server connection in your chat application. Server will notify your clients whenever server data changes. Take a look at http://socket.io/

Answer (score 0):

please look at this. 
It will call the function for every (time you set).
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?194202-Autorefresh-List-with-DelayedTask