# Displaying count down timer in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I need to display a countdown timer, implemented it using delayed task.
code as below:

```
var task = Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', function() {

if (sec < 1 && min > 0) {
    min--;
    sec = 60;
}
if (min == 0 && sec == 1) {
    task.cancel();
}
sec--;
Ext.getCmp('minute').setHtml(min);
Ext.getCmp('second').setHtml(sec);
console.log('minute is' + min + 'second is' + sec);

task.delay(1000);

}, this);

task.delay(1000);
```

With the above implementation, function gets called only once.
Looking at the discussion at this thread
[Auto Refresh the List in Sencha Touch Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697434/auto-refresh-the-list-in-sencha-touch-application) the above code should work. But, it is not working. What could be wrong in my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Ext.util.DelayedTask is meant for delaying a task without executing it.
This can be useful for delaying an Ajax-call on a form, as you can see in the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.util.DelayedTask):

> This method is especially useful for things like detecting whether a user has finished typing in a text field. [..] You can use this class to buffer the keypress events for a certain number of milliseconds, and perform only if they stop for that amount of time.

Why don't you just use a regular setTimeout? Something like http://jsfiddle.net/EreaP/ works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be the better solution for me. But, why the callback was not called after the first execution?

Comment: Because DelayedTask executes a **single** call. In your code above you created the task and delayed it for 1 second. After a second the single call gets executed, then you can't delay it anymore (after execution)

Answer (score 0):

Late response:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.TimerClock', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'timerClock',
    duration: 3 * 60 * 60, //default to 3 hour
    paused: false,
    clockIntervalHook: undefined,
    config: {
        listeners: {
            initialize: function () {
                this.start();
            }
        }
    },
    start: function () {
        var me = this,
            duration = me.duration,
            updateClock = function () {
                if (me.isPaused()) {
                    return;
                }
                me.setHtml(me.formatTime(duration--));
                if (duration <= 0) {
                    me.stop();
                }
            };
        me.clockIntervalHook = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
        return me;
    },

    pause: function () {
        this.paused = true;
        return this;
    },

    isPaused: function () {
        return this.paused == true
    },

    resume: function () {
        this.paused = false;
    },

    restart: function () {
        this.stop();
        this.start();
    },

    stop: function () {
        clearInterval(this.clockIntervalHook);
        return this;
    },

    //format the given seconds into "HH:MM:SS" format
    //override this if you need custom behavior
    formatTime: function (seconds) {
        var hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
        hours = hours <= 9 ? "0" + hours : hours;
        seconds %= 3600;
        var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        minutes = minutes <= 9 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds %= 60;
        seconds = seconds <= 9 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds
    }
});
```

Any other view, add the timer simply using

```
{ xtype : 'timerClock' }
```